# Calculate same values but for different product type in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 
    [PlayerId],
    SUM(Aggr.TotalBetAmount)                    [TotalBets], 
    SUM(Aggr.TotalBetCount)                     [TotalBetCount], 
    SUM(Aggr.RealMoneyBetAmount)                [RealMoneyBets], 
    SUM(Aggr.BonusMoneyBetAmount)               [BonusBets], 
    SUM(Aggr.RedeemedBonusBetAmount)            [RedeemedBonusBets], 
    SUM(Aggr.FinancialBetAmount)                [FinanceBets],
    SUM(Aggr.TotalWinAmount)                    [TotalWins], 
    SUM(Aggr.RealMoneyWinAmount)                [RealMoneyWins],
    SUM(Aggr.BonusMoneyWinAmount)               [BonusWins],
    SUM(Aggr.RedeemedBonusWinAmount)            [RedeemedBonusWins],
    SUM(Aggr.FinancialWinAmount)                [FinanceWins],
    SUM(Aggr.TotalGrossWinAmount)               [TotalIncome],
    SUM(Aggr.RealMoneyGrossWinAmount)           [RealMoneyIncome],
    SUM(Aggr.BonusMoneyGrossWinAmount)          [BonusMoneyIncome],
    SUM(Aggr.RedeemedBonusMoneyGrossWinAmount)  [RedeemedBonusIncome],
    SUM(Aggr.FinancialGrossWinAmount)           [FinancialTotalIncome],
    SUM(Aggr.NetIncomeAmount)                   [NetIncome],
    SUM(Aggr.RedeemedNetBonusIncomeAmount)      [RedeemedNetBonusIncomeAmount],
    SUM(Aggr.BonusMarketingCostAmount)          [RedeemedBonusCash],
    SUM(Aggr.BonusBalanceCorrectionAmount)      [BonusBalanceCorrection],
    SUM(Aggr.[RedeemedNetBonusIncomeAmount])    [CasinoRedeemedNetBonusIncomeAmount]      
FROM 
    [WarehouseMgmt].[FactWalletAgr] Aggr
JOIN 
    [WarehouseMgmt].[DimGame] DG ON Aggr.GameId = DG.Id
JOIN 
    [WarehouseMgmt].[DimPlayer] DPL ON Aggr.[PlayerId] = DPL.[Id]
JOIN 
    [WarehouseMgmt].[DimProductTypeMapGroup] PTMG ON PTMG.ProductTypeId = Aggr.ProductTypeId
WHERE 
    (TimeId BETWEEN @DimStartDateUTC AND @DimEndDateUTC)
    AND PTMG.MapGroupId = @CasinoProductType ' +@sqlFilters+ '
GROUP BY 
    [PlayerId]
```

and my question: how can I calculate `TotalBetAmount`, `TotalBetCount`, `RealMoneyBetAmount`,... for different product types from the same table `[WarehouseMgmt].[FactWalletAgr]` but without to limit in where for just one product type `PTMG.MapGroupId = @CasinoProductType`?

I want to somehow have a query that will calculate also for `SportsBook`, `Poker` and `Casino` product type, but not to have 3 different copy-paste queries. Just one same query and somehow to be able to but right values for right product type

Comment: please improve your question https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to `group by [MapGroupId]`.

```
 SELECT 
                     [PlayerId], 
                     [MapGroupId],
                     SUM(Aggr.TotalBetAmount)                               [TotalBets], 
                     SUM(Aggr.TotalBetCount)                                [TotalBetCount], 
                     SUM(Aggr.RealMoneyBetAmount)                           [RealMoneyBets], 
                     SUM(Aggr.BonusMoneyBetAmount)                          [BonusBets], 
                     SUM(Aggr.RedeemedBonusBetAmount)                       [RedeemedBonusBets], 
                     SUM(Aggr.FinancialBetAmount)                           [FinanceBets],
                     SUM(Aggr.TotalWinAmount)                               [TotalWins], 
                     SUM(Aggr.RealMoneyWinAmount)                           [RealMoneyWins],
                     SUM(Aggr.BonusMoneyWinAmount)                          [BonusWins],
                     SUM(Aggr.RedeemedBonusWinAmount)                       [RedeemedBonusWins],
                     SUM(Aggr.FinancialWinAmount)                           [FinanceWins],
                     SUM(Aggr.TotalGrossWinAmount)                          [TotalIncome],
                     SUM(Aggr.RealMoneyGrossWinAmount)                      [RealMoneyIncome],
                     SUM(Aggr.BonusMoneyGrossWinAmount)                     [BonusMoneyIncome],
                     SUM(Aggr.RedeemedBonusMoneyGrossWinAmount)             [RedeemedBonusIncome],
                     SUM(Aggr.FinancialGrossWinAmount)                      [FinancialTotalIncome],
                     SUM(Aggr.NetIncomeAmount)                              [NetIncome],
                     SUM(Aggr.RedeemedNetBonusIncomeAmount)                 [RedeemedNetBonusIncomeAmount],
                     SUM(Aggr.BonusMarketingCostAmount)                     [RedeemedBonusCash],
                     SUM(Aggr.BonusBalanceCorrectionAmount)                 [BonusBalanceCorrection],
                     SUM(Aggr.[RedeemedNetBonusIncomeAmount])               [CasinoRedeemedNetBonusIncomeAmount]      
              FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[FactWalletAgr] Aggr
              JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimGame] DG ON Aggr.GameId = DG.Id
              JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimPlayer] DPL ON Aggr.[PlayerId] = DPL.[Id]
              JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimProductTypeMapGroup] PTMG ON PTMG.ProductTypeId = Aggr.ProductTypeId
              WHERE (TimeId BETWEEN @DimStartDateUTC AND @DimEndDateUTC)
              AND PTMG.MapGroupId IN ( @CasinoProductType, @SportsBook, ...)  ' +@sqlFilters+ '
              GROUP BY [PlayerId], [MapGroupId]
```